# Valgrind-Uninitialised value error with getline() function

Tags: c, valgrind, getline

I want to read multiple lines from a text file by a loop, but I always get `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)` error in my `getline()` line.

My code:

```
char *string;
size_t len = 0;   

while (getline(&string, &len, fileStream) != -1) { // error happens this line   
    // do something  
}

free(string);   
fclose(fileSream);
```

I tried but failed to fix it. Any solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: Where is `fileStream` declaration and initialization?

Comment: @ouah `fileStream` is already initialized. It has nothing to do with my problem, so I just omit them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do either of below.

1. set `char *string = NULL;` and `len` to `0`. <sup>[[ Preferred Method ]]</sup>
2. allocate memory to `char *string` and send the size of allocated memory using `len`.

Related quotes from [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) for referrence

```
   If *lineptr is set to NULL and *n is set 0 before the call, then
   getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line.  This buffer
   should be freed by the user program even if getline() failed.

   Alternatively, before calling getline(), *lineptr can contain a
   pointer to a malloc(3)-allocated buffer *n bytes in size.  If the
   buffer is not large enough to hold the line, getline() resizes it
   with realloc(3), updating *lineptr and *n as necessary.
```

Comment: But the second solution will cause memory leak.

Comment: you need to `free()` the memory from user application in both the cases. why'd you say that about only second approach?

Comment: I usually initialize to NULL (freeing the value before of course) and reinit to NULL and 0 at the end of loop

Comment: @dvhh IMO, that's the best way. However, just wanted to share the options available.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes, the second one is also correct. I just didn't think I should free `string` before `while` loop. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for me it was easily solved by initializing string and len but also by initializing an int for getline, example

```
int gline = 0;

while (gline = getline(&string, &len, fileStream)) != -1
```

Comment: Your pseudo code does not "initialize" the string at all